# pandas groupby numeric functions coerce numeric to object when DataFrame contains object

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas groupby function on a DataFrame which has mixed types (numeric and objects).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> d = {
...  "sales": {
...   "0": 3963.0,
...   "1": 2312.7,
...  },
...  "Id": {
...   "0": 10001,
...   "1": 10003,
...  },
...  "Blah": {
...   "0": "Blah1",
...   "1": "Blah2",
...  }
... }
>>> 
>>> d=pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> 
>>> print d.dtypes
Blah      object
Id         int64
sales    float64
dtype: object
```

When I apply a numeric function to the group, such as max() or mean(), I get a DataFrame with type `object` returned

```
>>> print d.groupby('Id').max()['sales']
Id
10001    3963.0
10003    2312.7
Name: sales, dtype: object
```

When I select only numeric columns first and then apply a numeric function to the group, such as max() or mean(), I get a DataFrame with a numeric type

```
>>> print d[['sales','Id']].groupby('Id').max()['sales']
Id
10001    3963.0
10003    2312.7
Name: sales, dtype: float64
```

This second result is what I would expect - or rather I don't understand why applying a numeric function `max` or `mean` to a dataframe with non-numeric types would coerce numeric values to objects.

For example, without the non-numeric object type in the original dataframe the types are not coerced in a weird fashion:

```
>>> del d['Blah']
>>> d[['Id','sales']].groupby('Id').max()['sales']
Id
10001    3963.0
10003    2312.7
Name: sales, dtype: float64
>>> d.groupby('Id').max()['sales']
Id
10001    3963.0
10003    2312.7
Name: sales, dtype: float64
>>>
```

Edit - here's my version info:

```
Mac OS X 10.9 w/ Python 2.7.6
Cython==0.19.2
matplotlib==1.3.1
numpy==1.8.0
pandas==0.13.1
scipy==0.13.0
```

Comment: Is your question just why it works this way, or is it causing a specific problem for you?  (I don't know why it works that why myself, although there is [an old bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/237) that looks similar.)

Comment: I'm wondering if it is a bug - or if not, why it works that way. I think it is a bug, because the unsuspecting user might expect types to be respected and be caught out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't recall exactly when this was fixed, but is correct in master/0.14 (coming soon).

```
In [48]: d
Out[48]: 
    Blah     Id   sales
0  Blah1  10001  3963.0
1  Blah2  10003  2312.7

[2 rows x 3 columns]

In [49]: d.dtypes
Out[49]: 
Blah      object
Id         int64
sales    float64
dtype: object

In [50]: d.groupby('Id').max()['sales']
Out[50]: 
Id
10001    3963.0
10003    2312.7
Name: sales, dtype: float64
```